# how would you protect a file from being downloaded by anyone not logged in on a Yii2 project?

Tags: php, web, yii2

Basically, i'm using a standard Yii2 set up. i have a login that allows a user to see links to files. the files are in a download folder.. but the page to see the links is only able to be seen if a user is "not guest." now, if anyone just copies the link to someone else, that other person will be able to download the file without being logged in. the files in question aren't being "paid for" BUT i am required to have people login before they are allowed to download them becuase of terms of service and other laws. can i dynamically create download links via php? at least check for "isGuest" and if isGuest = True then redirect to login page. how would i do that instead of just having a direct download link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide acces to an specific action to specific roles or users with [AccessControl Class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#access-control-filter) .

You can do something like this:

```
class DownloadController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => false,
                        'actions' => ['download'],
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
    // ...
}
```

`'?'` Role are the guest users.

Comment: so much thanks! this is what i needed. plus the first answer of how to directly forbid files.

Comment: so basically make an "everyone logged in group" and replace '?' and that's perfect. just define the action to use the "sendFile" method? very nice. basically, example.org/index.php?download="stuff.mp3" instead of example.org/downloads/stuff.mp3? that's awesome. so much thanks.

Comment: Hello @Sageth,
How to handle this in Zend Framework 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check in your controller's action to validate if the user is logged in or not, using:

`Yii::$app->user->getIsGuest();`

Look at the documentation for more details: [Yii2 web user](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html)

Comment: i know how to check for IsGuest, though, thank you for answering. as the other person said, i need to pass the file through a controller that checks for isGuest. not a directly download. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Forbid access for anyone to the file to direct download. You can do so with htaccess or by putting the download folder into yiis protected folder. Now you need a download action in a controller where you check if the user is guest or logged in. If ok, simply pass the file through from your filesystem and to the users browser. [phps readfile](http://php.net/manual/de/function.readfile.php) can help you here.

Comment: super super thanks! you an the third answer helped so much. thanks!